# Install nuget packages with permissions

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

using vs 2017  is it possible to control/permission who can install packages in a solution without using Team Services or other third party tool?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to control/permission who can install packages in a solution without using Team Services or other third party tool?

To my knowledge, we could not set permission who can install packages from NuGet gallery without VSTS or third party tool. That because the gallery has not been implemented for this, but you can **set up a NuGet server that is accessible via https from the internet**, and only allows people who can successfully authenticate to view or download the packages on the server.

You can refer to [how to set NuGet.Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/nuget-server) and [how to Configuring NuGet server to use Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928112/configuring-nuget-server-to-use-authentication) for detail info.