# How to get packages list from nuget server?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, private-nuget-feed

I want to list the packages on a private nuget server. How can I do the authentication process.

Comment: you could use an apikey. you can setup an apikey in the web.config of the nuget-server and then use it in your requests

Comment: Do you have a document or a project about how it's done?

Comment: i would recommend https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/ as your starting point. there are links to all relevant docs you need. i also found that there is a thread on SO about one way to enable and use authentication https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928112/configuring-nuget-server-to-use-authentication